# Avoid moving cursor on autcmd BufWritePre in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I have the following line in my `.vimrc`.

```
autocmd BufWritePre * silent! v/\_s*\S/d
```

This strips empty lines at the ends of files, on save. The problem is, when it strips the lines it also moves the cursor to the last line of the file. Is there anyway to avoid modifying the cursor location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function! <SID>DelEmptyLinesEnd()
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    v/\_s*\S/d
    call cursor(l, c)
endfunction

autocmd BufWritePre * :call <SID>DelEmptyLinesEnd()
```